# Is is possible to run android app automation test on linux server

Tags: android, linux, simulator

There is a virtual CentOS linux server, here is some info about this server:
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)
Release:        7.0.1406
Codename:       Core

Is is possible to run android app automation test on it?
Maybe one solution is installing android simulator first, then deploy the app to the simulator through adb, then run the automation script....
However, the linux server is pure text, it does't has any ui library installed. so the simulator can't work.  How to achieve the automation test goal ? any comments are appreciatived.

Comment: able to find answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No!

I'm sorry to have to be the one to say this, but no, it will never work!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [Selendroid](http://selendroid.io/): it's a Java framework for test automation that works with Android simulator and real devices.